# mPDF doesn't print Hebrew on the pdf file

Tags: php, mpdf

I have this problem using `mPDF` with hebrew language.

These are mPDF and PHP versions I am using
PHP: 5.6.25
mPDF: up to date

#### This is a PHP code snippet I use

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8');
$mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1 lang="he">sssשדגשדגשדג</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

as you can see, I have added utf8 charset and set direction to rtl.

when I exec the code I get only the `sss` letters without the hebrew I think its ignore them.

THANKS~

Comment: Did you save the PHP file in utf-8 encoding? Which font do you use? Maybe that font don't have hebrew characters

Comment: Thx, it was the font. I have added `$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;` to the code.

Answer (score 4):

Just put this in your code before $mpdf->WriteHTML();

```
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```