# how to display hindi marathi font on mpdf from database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I fetch data from mysql which contain book name (in english and hindi/marathi font).
When i tried to generate pdf (using mpdf) of some data i got below things
[image]

I tried using some css but its not working

```css
p,
td {
  font-family: freeserif;
}
```

I was working on live server
if i use

> font-family: freeserif;

in inline css then pdf dont work.

please guide me someone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mPDF doesn't print Hebrew on the pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337384/mpdf-doesnt-print-hebrew-on-the-pdf-file)

Comment: check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412203/dompdf-and-set-different-font-family

Comment: @voiarn No thats not my question

Comment: still not working @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi

Comment: Voiarn's post is likely to be talking about a similar issue, even if the specific language is different. Give it a try, at least.

Comment: @ADyson
I tried voiarn link, but now pdf not visible

Comment: What do you mean "not visible"? You mean the code crashes and doesn't create it, or something? Try to be more precise about the problem.

Comment: @ADyson
I received fetal error "Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Cannot find TTF TrueType font file "FreeSerif.ttf" in configured font directories. in /home/u665034481/domains/mylibrarywala.com/public_html/admin/mpdf/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Fonts/FontFileFinder.php:33 Stack trace: #0"

Comment: That probably just means you need to download the mentioned font file...